# Tracking and grouping parameter based Goal Destination URL in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a `reservation.php` page and on success, the page returns/post a 5 digit Confirmation No. as part of the URL. e.g. `/reservation.php?Success=&ConfirmationNo=29564`

In Google Analytics > Admin > Goals Detail > Destination URL, I have set the type "Begins with" and set the URL to `/reservation.php?Success=&ConfirmationNo=` But in Reporting > Conversions > Goals > Overview, it do not group (Goal Completion Location) all reservations into one goal URL instead showing each reservation URL separately. e.g.

Goal Completion Location:

1. `/reservation.php?Success=&ConfirmationNo=29566`
2. `/reservation.php?Success=&ConfirmationNo=29567`
3. `/reservation.php?Success=&ConfirmationNo=29568`

So I unable to compare the number of reservations with the previous month. I want it to show something like `/reservation.php?Success=&ConfirmationNo=` as one location with number of reservations in a period selected.

I tried to add . or * or .* at the end of URL and selected both "Begins with" and regular expression to group all the reservations but "Verify this goal" tool do not accept any of these and shows 0% completion in last 7 days.

Can you please help how can I group all my reservations into 1 Goal Completion Location?

Answer (score 0):

Well Google Analytics does exactly what you told it to do. There are two different things:

- Goal - a goal is triggered when the URL starts with /reservation.php?Success=&ConfirmationNo=
- Goal completion location - simply shows the actual location where the goal happened

If you want to compare goals by month, go to Conversions -> Goals -> Overview. At the top left, choose name of your target in the dropdown menu (below segments). At the top right, choose grouping by month. At the very top right, choose the time period for which you want to compare data (at least two months).

Now you will see the chart of number of goals per each month in the specified time period.

---

If you are still unhappy with this reporting, then pass the variable ConfirmationNo in the $_POST field instead of the $_GET field.